# Azure Functions Authentication - disable on single endpoint?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am using Functions version 3 with the Authentication preview.

[image]

It works well and properly validates incoming tokens against the AAD, however, I need one endpoint to be public (or with code) and this is not possible at the moment at all as authLevel in function does not have any effect on the built-in authentication.

Is it possible to make one endpoint to be excluded from the Auth?

Comment: Can I understand your question like you owned several http trigger functions and you wanna make one of them can be accessed anonymous while others needed authentication?

Comment: No, you can not.

Comment: If you don't want built-in authentication, you can change it from function level to anonymous.

Comment: Function with anonymous is still protected by the built-in auth.

Comment: deploying another same function for public access could be a workaround

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, we cannot set different authentication levels for different `functions in the same` Function App`.

As `Stanley` mentioned in the comments, you can create a publicly accessible `Function App`. You can choose `consumption plan`, which is billed according to the number of executions, and there will not be more costs.